# What's this recurring progression in Hallel?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, tehilim-psalms

Commonly recited from Psalms is [Chapter 118](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.118), recited in Hallel on Rosh Chodesh and Festivals. It begins (v. 1-4):

> הוֹד֣וּ לַיהוָ֣ה כִּי־ט֑וֹב כִּ֖י לְעוֹלָ֣ם חַסְדּֽוֹ׃
>
> Praise the LORD, for He is good,
> His steadfast love is eternal.
>
> יֹֽאמַר־נָ֥א יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל כִּ֖י לְעוֹלָ֣ם חַסְדּֽוֹ׃
>
> Let Israel declare, “His steadfast love is eternal.”
>
> יֹֽאמְרוּ־נָ֥א בֵֽית־אַהֲרֹ֑ן כִּ֖י לְעוֹלָ֣ם חַסְדּֽוֹ׃
>
> Let the house of Aaron declare, “His steadfast love is eternal.”
>
> יֹֽאמְרוּ־נָ֭א יִרְאֵ֣י יְהוָ֑ה כִּ֖י לְעוֹלָ֣ם חַסְדּֽוֹ׃
>
> Let those who fear the LORD declare, “His steadfast love is eternal.”

There seems to be a progression of mentioning something about Israel, the house of Aharon, and then those who fear Hashem. I didn't think much of this, until I noticed the same progression appears earlier in [Chapter 115:9-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.115.9-11), in the part that's only recited with full Hallel:

> יִ֭שְׂרָאֵל בְּטַ֣ח בַּיהוָ֑ה עֶזְרָ֖ם וּמָגִנָּ֣ם הֽוּא׃
>
> O Israel, trust in the LORD! He is their help and shield.
>
> בֵּ֣ית אַ֭הֲרֹן בִּטְח֣וּ בַיהוָ֑ה עֶזְרָ֖ם וּמָגִנָּ֣ם הֽוּא׃
>
> O house of Aaron, trust in the LORD! He is their help and shield.
>
> יִרְאֵ֣י יְ֭הוָה בִּטְח֣וּ בַיהוָ֑ה עֶזְרָ֖ם וּמָגִנָּ֣ם הֽוּא׃
>
> O you who fear the LORD, trust in the LORD! He is their help and shield.

Again, it mentions Israel, the house of Aharon, and those who fear Hashem.

Do any commentaries pick up on this and explain its significance?

Comment: 135:19 as well.

Comment: The Radak and Even Ezra seem to address this question on these pesukim. Interestingly, Rashi interprets Yarei Hashem differently. In one case he says it’s shevet levi in another place he says it’s converts (possibly what Even Ezra means as well)

Comment: @Chatzkel it's Ibn Ezra

Comment: Indeed. My mistake. Thanks

Comment: Same progression as ,יברך את בית ישראל, יברך את בית אהרון, יברך יראי ה'

Answer (score 3):

They look similar but yet each is a bit different.

From Midrash Hallel
115

In the theme of the psalm, the first sequence says

1. Trust in H' the true living God and do not stray to the breakable idols of the other nations.
2. Like Aharon stood against the Korach insurrection.. comparable to idolatry
3. Like Abraham the iconoclast. (and Rashi says yerei H are gerim)

Zakhareinu yevarekh.. By parable

1. A Kohen comes to the Queen and asks his reward, she says what for, he says bc I'm a Kohen, she gives him
2. A Levi .. same
3. Someone comes and says but I have fear of sin, without that the other two are nothing.

https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C/%D7%92

> ישראל בטח בה', שהוא אלהינו הוא אלהים חיים ומלך עולם חי וקים לעולם ולעולמי עולמים, אתם ישראל הוו זהירין שלא יטריחו לכם אומות העולם בדברים ויאמרו אלהותינו אומרים לנו דרך נלך בם ומשתברים אותם בידם שנא' הבל המה מעשה תעתועים, לא כאלה חלק יעקב.
> בית אהרן בטחו בה', הזהרו בעמידה שעמדתי לאהרן אביכם על דבר קרח שנאמר ותפתח הארץ את פיה ותבלע אותם, וכן בעוזיהו שהיה מצורע עד יום מותו.
> יראי ה' בטחו בה', הזהרו בעמידה שעמדתי לאברהם אביכם שהיה ירא חטא לפני שנאמר כי עתה ידעתי כי ירא אלהים אתה אף אני עמדתי והצלתיו מאור כשדים שנא' אני ה' אשר הוצאתיך מאור כשדים.
> ה' זכרנו יברך יברך את בית ישראל יברך את בית אהרן יברך יראי ה' – משל למה הדבר דומה לאחד שהלך אצל מטרונה אחת אמר לה תני לי חלקי שאני כהן והיא נתנה לו, בא אחר ואמר לה תני לי חלקי שאני לוי ונתנה לו, בא שלישי אמר לה תני לי חלקי אמרה לו ומה טיבך אמר לה ראשון שהיה כהן אין בו יראת חטא אין בו כלום, וכן השני אבל אני כהן גדול מכהן ומלוי שאני ירא חטא שנאמר והריחו ביראת ה' ואומר יראת ה' היא אוצרו.

Ch. 118

Parable.

1. A man can't say he's good, rather Yisrael give witness H is good.
2. The town says the king is good in his dealings but only his servants, Levi and Kohen, know specifically what he's done in his dealings that he's kind.
3. Even though we know his in house conduct, only his associates and advisors of goodness know whom he consults with.  And who are they? The Tzadikim

> יאמר נא ישראל כי לעולם חסדו, לא יוכל אדם לומר על עצמו (יאמר אדם עליו) שהוא טוב אלא אחרים יהיו מעידים עליו, ומי מעיד על הקב"ה שהוא טוב ישראל לכך נאמר יאמר נא ישראל כי לעולם חסדו.
> יאמרו נא בית אהרן כי לעולם חסדו, משל למה הדבר דומה לבעל הבית שהיה נוהג עם אריסיו מנהג יפה בשעת חשבון אין מדקדק עמהם, בשעת הגורן משייר להם שיורי הגורן והיה נוהג עמהם יפה יפה, והיו בני העיר אומרים זכור בעל הבית לטובה שהוא נוהג עם אריסיו מנהג יפה, בשעת חשבון אין מדקדק עמהם, אבל אין יודעים מתוך משאו ומתנו בתוך ביתו מה הוא, ומי יודע משאו ומתנו בתוך ביתו אלא עבדיו ובני פלטורין שלו, ומי הם עבדיו של הקב"ה אלו הם כהנים בני אהרן שמקריבים קרבנות ושלמים וקטורת לכך נאמר יאמרו נא בית אהרן כי לעולם חסדו.
> יאמרו נא יראי ה' כי לעולם חסדו, אף על פי שאנו יודעים משאו ומתנו בתוך ביתו אין אנו יודעים עם מי נושא ונותן עצה אלא סנקתדרין שלו ויועצי רחמיו של הקב"ה ומי הם אלו הצדיקים לכך נאמר יאמרו נא יראי ה' כי לעולם חסדו.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Artscroll commentary](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/TSSH.html) on Tehillim it writes (Vol. 2, p.1402) as follows:

> כל לעולם חסדו - *His kindness endures forever*: Abarbanel explains that this phrase refers to clearly revealed acts of kindness. Often, this visible kindness is followed by periods of הסתר פנים *concealment of Divine Presence*. The Psalmist reassures Israel that G-d's *kindness endures forever* and that it will definitely manifest itself again after the period of concealment.
>
> **In the next three verses, the Psalmist exhorts various groups to repeat the second part of the verse (but not the first part) because although these groups will praise G-d for specific acts of Divine *kindness* which they have witnessed, they do not always appreciate G-d's constant, unfailing goodness (which is lauded in the first section of the verse).**

In a similar vein, it is worth noting the Maharal on Tehillim 115:9 where he writes:

> ישראל בטח בה' - זכר ג' כתות, בית ישראל, בית אהרן, ירא ה'. פירוש, כי אלו ג' כתות, ישראל, מצד שהם בניו, הרי הם דבקים בעצם. [כי] כמו שיש דביקות [מצד] הבן אל האב, כך יש דביקות [מצד] ישראל לאביהן שבשמים. ומפני כך ראוי להם לבטוח בו יתברך, מצד הדביקות הזה. אמנם 'בית אהרן' עובדים לא מאהבה, כמו מי שהוא אוהב את אחר, כך הם בית אהרן אוהבים [את] הקדוש ברוך הוא עובדים מאהבה, וזהו הדביקות הזה מצד האהבה. ואחר כך זכר 'יראי ה' בטחו בה'', שהם עובדים השם מיראה, ומצד היראה יש להם דביקות בו יתברך. הנה ג'כתות, הא' בית ישראל דביקות עצמי, מה שהם בנים אל השם יתברך. בית אהרן אוהבים אל הקדוש ברוך הוא, ועובדים לפניו [מאהבה]. הג' יראי ה', עובדים מיראה. ועוד יתבארו אלו ג' כתות. ובמזמור 'הללו עבדי ה'' זכר גם [את] 'בית הלוי', אבל [כאן] בכל ההלל לא זכר 'בית הלוי'. והטעם, מפני כי כל הלל [לא בא אלא] על החסד והטוב שהקדוש ברוך הוא עושה עם ישראל. ומפני שהלוים דבקים במדת הדין, ולא יבא מזאת המדה החסד והטוב, לכך בכל ההלל לא נזכר כלל בית הלוי
>
> O' Israel! Trust in Hashem - This is a reminder of three groups: 1) The House of Israel, 2) The House of Aharon & 3) Those who fear Hashem. These three groups can be explained as follows: Israel - from the perspective that they are His sons and they are actually clinging to Him, because it is like the clinging of a son to his father, so too Israel cleave to their father in Heaven. Accordingly, they deserve to be blessed in Him, due to this attachment. However, 'the House of Aharon' serve not out of love. It is like
> one who loves another, so too the house of Aaron love [the] Blessed One who serves out of love, and it this attachment from the perspective of love. And after that we mention "You who fear Hashem - trust in Hashem, since they love out of fear. And from the perspective of fear they have an attachment to Hashem. Thus we have three groups; the first is the house of Israel which is a personal attachment like that of sons to Hashem. The House of Aharon who love Hashem and serve Him out love, And the third, those who fear Hashem who serve out of fear. And one can explain these three groups further. In the song, "Servants of Hashem, give praise" it also mentions 'the house of Levi" and yet in the rest of Hallel it doesn't mention the house of Levi? And the reason is because all of Hallel [does not come except] for the grace and goodness that Hashem does with Israel. And because the Leviim adhere to the measure of law, the measure of grace and goodness will not come from this, and so it 'the house of Levi' is not mentioned at all in Hallel.

So we see from the Maharal that these groups each have a different basis for serving Hashem and that is why we mention each one in turn.

Comment: What do you mean Maharal on Tehillim 115:9. He wrote a commentary on tehillim?

Comment: @robev - https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=144912&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=1

Comment: He didn't write that. That's just a likkut of his comments elsewhere. I'd cite the original location. If you don't have a chance I'll see if I can do it.

Comment: I can't see where he sources it from? https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=144912&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=366

Answer (score 1):

In his commentary to Tehillim 115:10, Malbim explains that this progression is one of greater bitachon and higher spiritual level, which leads to greater help from Hashem:

> ומפרש שכל שיגדל הבטחון ומעלת הבוטח כן יגדל העזר וההגנה, עד שבית אהרן שגדול מעלתם ובטחונם מבית ישראל כן עזרם ומגנם הוא בעזר פרטי יתר על בית ישראל, וכן יראי ה׳ שגדול מעלתם מבית אהרן מצד שהם עובדים ע״י בחירתם בקדושה מופלגת יותר, יגדל עזרם ביחוד.

Since they received greater help from Hashem, they must each add a level of thanks to Hashem, so the progression follows the same order. As Malbim writes in 118:2:

> וביחוד יודוהו ישראל שעמהם עשה טובה פרטית יותר, ובית אהרן שהם קבלו יותר טובות פרטיות, וכן יראי ה׳, כל אחד לפי רוב הטובה שקבל התחייב בהודאה יתירה